# Building ASP.NET Core 6 app with docker builds test projects that were not restored

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 6.x app that I want to deploy to Digital Ocean. Since they have no native support for dotnet, I need to dockerize the app. It builds and runs perfectly on my dev machine and the old production environment, but I am messing something up when it comes to building it.

This is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProject.API/MyProject.API/MyProject.API.csproj", "MyProject.API/"]
COPY ["MyProject.API/MyProject.API.Persistence/MyProject.API.Persistence.csproj", "MyProject.API.Persistence/"]
COPY ["MyProject.API/MyProject.API.Domain/MyProject.API.Domain.csproj", "MyProject.API.Domain/"]
COPY ["MyProject.API/MyProject.Social/MyProject.Social.csproj", "MyProject.Social/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject.API/MyProject.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyProject.API"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish --runtime alpine-x64 --no-self-contained

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
#COPY postgres.crt .
#COPY do-redis.crt .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.API.dll"]
```

It does everything up to the restore with no problems. It then gets to the `dotnet build` stage and the process stops. What you don't see in the Dockerfile above is that there are also two unit test projects in the solution. They are not restored by the `dotnet restore` which is as expected, as none of the projects actually reference the test projects - the test projects reference the web app / class libraries.

However, the build stage fails - it tries to build the test projects, and fails because it can't find Xunit etc. - nuget packages referenced by the test projects, but not restored in the previous dotnet step.

I guess I want one of two things to happen; either for `dotnet restore` to restore all projects, or for `dotnet build` to not build the non-restored unit test projects.

Or is my thinking entirely wrong on this? I can't see why it would behave like this, but my insight into the process is limited.

Thanks for any helps in getting this building

**EDIT** I forgot to add something, thanks to Kirk Larkin for pointing it out.

When I got this issue, I also tried to add the test project .csproj files to the four COPY commands in my current Dockerfile above.

```
COPY ["MyProject.API/MyProject.API.Tests/MyProject.API.Tests.csproj", "MyProject.API.Tests/"]
COPY ["MyProject.API/MyProject.Social/Tests/MyProject.Social.Tests.csproj", "MyProject.Social.Tests/"]
```

However, this did not cause them to get restored. I'm guessing this is because the MyProject.API.csproj file does not reference them - which it can't, as those projects refer to it, and that would cause a circular reference.

I also tried the copy commands above, and then running separate `dotnet restore` commands for each test project, but it still failed with the same errors.

Would the right "fix" perhaps be to create a build configuration based on Release called "Deploy" or something similar that just leaves the test projects out?

**EDIT 2** I tried creating a Build Configuration called "Deploy", based off of Release, but where the test projects are not built. I changed the `dotnet build` command to use the `-c Deploy` parameter. It stills insists on building the test projects and failing the build because it references Xunit and other "unrestored" packages.

Comment: If you want `dotnet restore` to restore the test projects, you need to copy the relevant *.csproj* files into the container along with the others, before running `dotnet restore`. Currently, when you run `dotnet restore`, the tests projects don't exist, so cannot be restored. When you run `dotnet build`, after `COPY . .`, the test projects do exist and are included in the build.

Comment: I knew I forgot to add something to my question - I have indeed tried to copy the .csproj files into the container by using the same type COPY commands as for the main app+libraries. This did not cause them to get restored, and the build still failed. Will edit my question with this information!

Comment: I would recommend looking at the build log to determine why it's attempting to build the test projects. There has to be _something_ that is referencing them to be causing this.

Comment: @MattThalman I will do that. However, the test projects do reference all of the library projects (the one in the top Dockerfile in the question) - wouldn't that make it impossible for any reference to go the other way, as that would make it circular?

Comment: I did a build with verbosity set to diag, and searching through it, there is not a single mention of the test projects. Which I find... weird.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, spent the weekend trying to debug this. Eventually gave up and built the Dockerfile from scratch.

Instead of copying across only the .csproj file, restoring them, then copying the rest, I now just `COPY . .` then `dotnet restore`. This works for some reason. I therefore think this is something funky that has happened to my project over time, and this is probably not a general solution to this problem. However, if you're from the future, looking for a solution to a similar problem, this is what apparently solved it for me.